# ms graph api. Timezone does not change in response

Tags: spring-mvc, outlook, retrofit, azure-ad-graph-api

First I'm using Java Spring Web app.

And I'd like to set timezone as "Tokyo Standard Time"

But, It doesn't work for me.

below is my code.

```
//Retrofit code
@Headers("Prefer: outlook.timezone=\"Tokyo Standard Time\"")
@POST("/v1.0/me/events")
Call<PagedResult<Event>> sendMessage(@Body Event event);
```

and this is timezone in body.

```
//Start timezone
DateTimeTimeZone Start_timezone = new DateTimeTimeZone();
Start_timezone.setTimeZone("Tokyo Standard Time");
...
```

If I send POST request, they always return(response) UTC timezone.

```
...
"start":{"dateTime":"2019-11-15T09:00:00.0000000","timeZone":"UTC"}
...
```

This is my request log,

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 380
Prefer: outlook.timezone="Tokyo Standard Time"
...
"start":{"dateTime":"2019-11-15T09:00:00Z","timeZone":"Tokyo Standard Time"},
...
```

POST request is normally working. but, The timezone does not change.

additionally, Timezone changes in Graph Explorer.

I have no idea what the problem is.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character 'Z' in your time string `2019-11-15T09:00:00Z` indicates that it is a UTC time, so graph API will ignore the 'Prefer' header.

Remove the 'Z' in your time string, it should work.

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me.
I was stupid enough to forget it.